# Modifying a list in scheme using built-in functions and map

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to design a function called changeList that modifies a list in scheme.

The function should drop each number between -1 and +1 inclusive. For each number greater than 1 it should replace the number with 10 times the number. For each number smaller than -1 it should replace the number with the absolute value of the reciprocal.

Here's the code I have so far

`(define (changeList x)
  (map (lambda (x)
         (if (> x 1) (* x 10)
             (* (/ 1 x) -1))) x))`

Here's an example of the desired output

`(changeList '(0 -2 3 -4 1))
-> '( 1/2 30 1/4 )`

I'm able to evaluate if x if greater than 1 and if x is smaller than -1, however I'm having issues adding the conditional statements to evaluate if the value is between -1 and 1 inclusively. I need to skip that value and not output it which I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better if first we get rid of the numbers in the range `[-1, 1]`: that's where `filter` will come in handy. After that, we can apply `map` to the result of the filtering step, implementing the required rules. This should do the trick:

```
(define (changeList lst)
  (map (λ (x) (if (> x 1) (* 10 x) (/ -1 x)))
       (filter (λ (x) (or (< x -1) (> x 1)))
               lst)))
```

In Racket we can do the filter-then-map idiom in a single step, and it'll also be more efficient:

```
(define (changeList lst)
  (filter-map (λ (x) (and (or (< x -1) (> x 1))
                          (if (> x 1) (* 10 x) (/ -1 x))))
              lst))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(changeList '(0 -2 3 -4 1))
=> '(1/2 30 1/4)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use the filter, but I wasn't able to evaluate correctly

Comment: Think of this as a pipeline: the output of one operation will be used as input for the next operation, that's how you connect together `filter`, `map`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In common lisp, one would use `mapcan`, which is `append-map` in Racket.
The results returned by the function given to `append-map` must return a list or `'()`.

```
(define (changeList lst)
  (append-map (lambda (x)
                (cond ((> x 1) (list (* x 10)))
                      ((< x -1) (list (* (/ 1 x) -1)))
                      (else '())))
              lst))
```

Always, if you want to use a `map` but sometimes no results should be collected,
you can use `append-map` and use `'()` as return value everywhere nothing should
be collected.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'd say that there's a more idiomatic and efficient way in Racket: just use `filter-map`. Take a look at my updated answer.